# Why does fit_transform keep throwing an error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, normalize

I've really been battling to understand why fit_transform keeps throwing an error. Debugging doesn't help much as it just sends me to the definition of an array and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pickle

def split_data(inputs, outputs, p_train=0.9, p_test=0.1):
    train_size = int(len(inputs) * p_train)
    test_size = int(len(inputs) * p_test)
    inputs_train, inputs_test = inputs[0:train_size, :], inputs[train_size:, :]
    outputs_train, outputs_test = outputs[0:train_size, :], outputs[train_size:, :]
    return inputs_train, inputs_test, outputs_train, outputs_test

rawinputs = pickle.load(open('rawinputs.pck', 'rb'))  
rawoutputs = pickle.load(open('rawoutputs.pck', 'rb'))  

#split
inputs_train, inputs_test, outputs_train, outputs_test = split_data(rawinputs, rawoutputs, p_train=0.90, p_test=0.10)

#normalize
scaler_inputs = MinMaxScaler()
inputs_train_scaled = scaler_inputs.fit_transform(inputs_train)
inputs_test_scaled = scaler_inputs.transform(inputs_test)
outputs_train = np.asmatrix(outputs_train)
```

The error get's thrown at the first line where fit_transform is used:

```py
inputs_train_scaled = scaler_inputs.fit_transform(inputs_train)
```

eg. of one row of rawinput data:

```
['28,7170876207375' '339,050018316624' '0,173448071160097' '158,211319524893']
```

error thrown:

```
File "C:\****\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 690, in fit_transform return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you could also post the full error and traceback you get. Also, an example of data you're using.

Comment: The values in your rawinput data look odd: Firstly they are strings. Secondly they look like floating-point numbers using comma as a decimal separator (German data source?). Thirdly the list expression is missing commas as element separators. Probably a typo by you?

Comment: The values are from a csv file which comes straight from the model I created, the format is a bit off because I printed the array from Pycharm, but the data should be a generic 2D array consisting of 4 float variables repeating over a specified number of time steps

Answer (score 0):

The key point is `inputs_train` variable must be 2-dimensional array.

Here a simple example for you:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
```

We will apply `MinMaxScaler` on to the face dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces

olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()

X = olivetti.images
y = olivetti.target
```

X is the face images, where y is the label of each face.

Next we will divide the dataset into the train and test set.

Similar to your `split_data` method.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()

X = olivetti.images
y = olivetti.target

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=42)
```

The `random_state` variable will help us to produce the same train and test set, each time we run the code.

Now if we look at the `x_train` variable:

```
print(x_train.shape)
```

[image]

There are 320 train images and each image is 64 x 64 pixels. We have to reshape to use `MinMaxScaler`

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2])
```

Now the new image size:

[image]

Final code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()

X = olivetti.images
y = olivetti.target

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=42)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2])
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1] * x_test.shape[2])

min_max_obj = MinMaxScaler()

inputs_train_scaled = min_max_obj.fit_transform(X=x_train)
inputs_test_scaled = min_max_obj.transform(X=x_test)
```

Comment: I am trying to model a gas turbine and the input data I am using is a combination of a number of values from a model that will be used to predict certain output values. From my understanding, the array that I'm trying to fit_transform should already be 2-dimensional. The array consists of 4 values for a given time step, with multiple timesteps eg. [[20,3,15,5],[15,4,14,7]...] . Your explanation explains the error I am receiving, I'm just struggling to apply that to my current problem?

Comment: "The array consists of 4 values for a given time steps". For a given time step, the input size is 1 x 4. If you look at my example, the input size should be 1 x 2.  As I have mentioned in the example, I have converted (320, 64, 64) -> (320, 4096). Thats how I applied 'MinMaxScaler' Therefore, for a given time step the input size should be 1 x 2, for instance [[20, 3], [15, 4]...] instead of [[20, 3, 15, 5], [15, 4, 14, 7]...]. If you can't manipulate input data, perhağs you could use other preprocessing methods such as PCA